# How to use Angularjs filter to filter an array which has a binding to two select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have two select boxes (box 1 and box2) which are bound to a model array. When an option is selected in box 1, the item should not be displayed in box2 and vice versa. How can I do this in Angularjs.

Below is my HTML

```
<select class="form-control" name"box1" ng-model="data.box1" ng-options="sq.text for sq in array1.boxvalue | filter :data.box1" required><option value="">Choose 1</option></select>

<select class="form-control" name"box2" ng-model="data.box2" ng-options="sq.text for sq in array1.boxvalue | filter: data.box1"" required><option value="">Choose 2</option></select>

array1.boxvalue = {['id':1,'text':'test1'],['id':2,'text':'test2'],['id':3,'text':'test3']}
```

How can I achieve the following: When selected test1 in box1, box2 drop down should not display test1 and vice versa.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking correctly, you need a filter that will go through array and exclude the value you don't like.

*(I am writing code out of my head so I am not sure it works 100%.)*

```
app.filter('excludeValue', function() {
    return function(input, val) {
        var newArray = [];
        //Loop through all the results and remove the one that is not needed
        for( var n = 0 ; n < input.length; n++) { 
            //Check if current value is not the same as a value we need to exclude
            if(input[n] != val) { 
                newArray.push(input[n]);
            }
        } 
        return newArray;
    };
});
```

EDIT: Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mYDiKZ1kon9tLIJFvsvr)

Answer (score 0):

**View:**

```
   <select    ng-model="data.box1" 
  ng-options="sq.text for sq in array1 | filter: notinbox2" required></select>

<select    ng-model="data.box2" ng-options="sq.text for sq in array1 |filter: notinbox1" required></select>
```

**controller:**

```
$scope.array1 =[{'id':1,'text':'test1'},{'id':2,'text':'test2'},{'id':3,'text':'test3'}]
        $scope.data={}
        $scope.notinbox2 = function(item){
            if(item == $scope.data.box2)
                {
                return false

                }
            else 
                return true

        }
        $scope.notinbox1 = function(item){
            if(item == $scope.data.box1)
                {
                return false

                }
            else 
                return true

        }
```

simplied few things from ur question

Plunker [http://plnkr.co/edit/NM7ovJ3wIpLohYIiDsu2?p=info]